# Randomly split batches for time series CV

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, model-evaluation, randomness

In certain code snippets for time series prediction, I find sometimes that authors split their data to train and test sets (nothing unusual for the moment). But then the train data is split into random batches. My question: What is the purpose of splitting your data into random batches for training? Is it better in terms of learning?

It was certainly counter-intuitive at first since I have never randomly split a time series.